# How to add image background to JTable in clojure

Tags: java, clojure, clojure-java-interop

I wrote this program in clojure to add background image to a JTable. I am stuck with the `prepareRenderer` function. It seems like clojure cannot handle the first parameter `rd` (equivalent Java `TableCellRenderer rd`). I might have done it all wrong here and I am very grateful if someone can help me resolve this problem. To run the program just save it to a `tabletest.clj` file and type at the clojure prompt:

```
(load-file "tabletest.clj")
```

If you comment out the `prepareRenderer` function you can run the code successfully without seeing the background image.

Please provide your own image file for the JTable background. The program is listed below:

```
    (import '(javax.swing JFrame JTable JPanel JScrollPane)
            '(javax.swing.table DefaultTableModel TableCellRenderer)
            '(java.awt Component BorderLayout Dimension Image))
    (import javax.imageio.ImageIO)
    (import java.io.File)

    (defn tabletest []
         (let [tableData (to-array-2d [
                       ["numbers" "67890" "This"]
                               ["mo numbers" "2598790" "is"]
                               ["got Math" "2598774" "a"]
                               ["got Numbers" "1234567" "Column"]
                               ["got pi" "3.1415926" "Apple"]
                                  ])
               colNames (to-array ["Col Labels" "Go" "Here"])
               frame (JFrame. "Table Example")
               panel (JPanel.)
               sP (JScrollPane.)
               dataModel (DefaultTableModel. tableData colNames)
               table (proxy [JTable] [dataModel]
                 (prepareRenderer [rd row col] ; problem starts here
                      (proxy-super rd row col) ; Don't know how to translate
                                                       ; Java code below to clojure:
                  (.setOpaque this false)  ;if (c instanceof JComponent)
                                ; ((JComponent)c).setOpaque(false);

                  this
                 )
                 (paintComponent [g2d]
                  ;(proxy-super paintComponent g2d)
                  (def image (ImageIO/read (File. "GreenCar.png")))
                  (.drawImage g2d image 0 0 this)
                  (proxy-super paintComponent g2d)
                         )
                    )
              ]

              (.setCellSelectionEnabled table true)
              (.setOpaque table false)
              (.setPreferredSize sP (Dimension. 300 150))
              (.setView (.getViewport sP) table)
              (.add panel sP)
              (doto frame
                  (.setLayout (BorderLayout.))
                  (.add panel BorderLayout/CENTER)
                  (.setSize 400 200)
                  (.setVisible true)
              )
          )
      )

      (tabletest)
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is the line:

```
 (proxy-super rd row col)
```

The correct way to code it is:

```
 (def c (proxy-super prepareRenderer [rd row col]))
```

and the lines:

```
 (.setOpaque this false)
 this
```

to be replaced by:

```
 (if (instance? JComponent c)
     (.setOpaque c false))
 c
```